# Rounded map corners hide streetview close button

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I used css & corner images to get rounded corners on a map but when showing streetview the close button is under the image and can't be clicked. Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem recently... I  created a "frame" (ie: a div that acts like a like a "picture frame" that sits perfectly on top of the map div; position it absolutely if you need to) and apply the rounded effects and corner images to the frame instead of the map div.

Alternatively you could experiment with wrapping the map inside a parent div with overflow hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up binding an event to the top right div to close the street view on click.